# Getting page title with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get what's inside of the `title` tag but I can't get to do it. I am following some of the answers around stackoverflow that are supposed to work but for me they don't.

This is what I am doing:

```
require "open-uri"
require "uri"

def browse startpage, depth, block
    if depth > 0
        begin 
            open(startpage){ |f|
                block.call startpage, f
            }
        rescue
            return
        end
    end
end

browse("https://www.ruby-lang.org/es/", 2, lambda { |page_name, web|
    puts "Header information:"
    puts "Title: #{web.to_s.scan(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)}"
    puts "Base URI: #{web.base_uri}"
    puts "Content Type: #{web.content_type}"
    puts "Charset: #{web.charset}"
    puts "-----------------------------"
})
```

The title output is just `[]`, why?

Comment: Are you trying to do this using open-uri only? Why not use something like Nokogiri?

Comment: @daremkd yeah I saw Nokogiri serves this purpose, but I want to do it this way and I want to know why I am getting an empty list as the title. After all that is solved, a Nokogiri solution as an extra tip could be great as well.

Comment: It's highly discouraged you use regex to parse HTML tags. There could be thousands of nuances on ANY web page that could cause your regex not to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) returns a `File` object or passes it to the block (actually a `Tempfile` but that doesn't matter). Calling `to_s` just returns a string containing the object's class and its id:

```
open('https://www.ruby-lang.org/es/') do |f|
  f.to_s
end
#=> "#<File:0x007ff8e23bfb68>"
```

Scanning that string for a title is obviously useless:

```
"#<File:0x007ff8e23bfb68>".scan(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)
```

Instead, you have to [`read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-i-read) the file's content:

```
open('https://www.ruby-lang.org/es/') do |f|
  f.read
end
#=> "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n...</html>\n"
```

You can now scan the content for a `<title>` tag:

```
open('https://www.ruby-lang.org/es/') do |f|
  str = f.read
  str.scan(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)
end
#=> [["Lenguaje de Programaci\xC3\xB3n Ruby"]]
```

or, using [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org): (because [You can't parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477037))

```
open('https://www.ruby-lang.org/es/') do |f|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)
  doc.at_css('title').text
end
#=> "Lenguaje de Programación Ruby"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must insist on using `open-uri`, this one liner than get you the page title:

```
2.1.4 :008 > puts open('https://www.ruby-lang.org/es/').read.scan(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)
Lenguaje de Programación Ruby
 => nil
```

If you want to use something more complicated than this, please use `nokogiri` or `mechanize`. Thanks

Comment: `Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.ruby-lang.org/es/')).css('title').text` isn't that complicated

Comment: actually I prefer the way I was doing it because with `URL.extract` I get the link with absolute form, not relative. With Nokogiri I am getting the `href` and I want the whole link because the page will be processed. However, your solution with `open().read.scan()` is the same than I was doing. `read` is the same than `web.to_s` that I was doing. And I still have the same problem: the title is an empty list.